# Algorithm overwrites Numpy array elements, but not Python list elements

Tags: python, numpy

A while back, I had been testing a few different sorting algorithms for python, when I encountered this strange behaviour.

Using a merge sort implementation [copied from GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/), I noticed that my Numpy arrays were getting overwritten by the last element in the array, while built-in Python arrays were sorted correctly.

What is the cause of this behaviour? I have a hunch that it's somehow caused by pass-by-reference vs pass-by-value error, but I can't put my fingers down on what exactly is the cause, since it works for the built-in python array.

*Note: this behaviour also happens to some other algorithms, not just merge sort.*

---

Here is a reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np

def mergeSort(arr):
    if len(arr) >1:
        mid = len(arr)//2 #Finding the mid of the array 
        L = arr[:mid] # Dividing the array elements  
        R = arr[mid:] # into 2 halves 

        mergeSort(L) # Sorting the first half 
        mergeSort(R) # Sorting the second half 

        i = j = k = 0
        # Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] 
        while i < len(L) and j < len(R): 
            if L[i] < R[j]: 
#                 print (arr, L, R)
                arr[k] = L[i]
#                 print (arr, L, R)
                i+=1
            else:
#                 print (arr, L, R)
                arr[k] = R[j] # Problem happens here, R replaces L and messes up calculations for numpy
#                 print (arr, L, R)
                j+=1
            k+=1

        # Checking if any element was left 
        while i < len(L): 
            arr[k] = L[i] 
            i+=1
            k+=1

        while j < len(R): 
            arr[k] = R[j] 
            j+=1
            k+=1

array = ([1,2,3,0])
print (f'python array before {array}')
mergeSort(array)
print (f'python array after {array}')

print ('----------')

array = np.array([1,2,3,0])
print (f'numpy array before {array}')
mergeSort(array)
print (f'numpy array after {array}')
```

This is the console output:

```
python array before [1, 2, 3, 0]
python array after [0, 1, 2, 3]
----------
numpy array before [1 2 3 0]
numpy array after [0 0 0 0]
```

---

I've narrowed down the location of the overwrite down to the line:

`arr[k] = R[j]`

You can uncomment the print statements and see the overwrites as it happens:

```
python array before [1, 2, 3, 0]
[1, 2] [1] [2]
[1, 2] [1] [2]
[3, 0] [3] [0] <-- Before arr[k] = R[j]
[0, 0] [3] [0] <-- After arr[k] = R[j] -- OK
[1, 2, 3, 0] [1, 2] [0, 3]
[0, 2, 3, 0] [1, 2] [0, 3]
[0, 2, 3, 0] [1, 2] [0, 3]
[0, 1, 3, 0] [1, 2] [0, 3]
[0, 1, 3, 0] [1, 2] [0, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 0] [1, 2] [0, 3]
python array after [0, 1, 2, 3]
----------
numpy array before [1 2 3 0]
[1 2] [1] [2]
[1 2] [1] [2]
[3 0] [3] [0] <-- Before arr[k] = R[j]
[0 0] [0] [0] <-- After arr[k] = R[j] -- BAD
[1 2 0 0] [1 2] [0 0]
[0 2 0 0] [0 2] [0 0]
[0 2 0 0] [0 2] [0 0]
[0 0 0 0] [0 0] [0 0]
numpy array after [0 0 0 0]
```

---

*Reproduced with:*

`Python 3.8.3 + Numpy 1.19.0`

`Jupyter Notebook 5.7.9 + Python 3.6.5 + Numpy 1.14.3`

Comment: Basic slices in numpy are *views* of part of the array, whereas slices of python lists are *copies* of part of the list. So in the numpy case, if you modify elements of `L` or `R`, then you modify `arr`. If you change the line `L=arr[:mid]` to `L=arr.copy()[:mid]` and similarly the `R=` line, then the problem goes away.

Comment: See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html - "All arrays generated by basic slicing are always views of the original array."

Comment: Now too late to edit my first comment above, but `arr[:mid].copy()` would probably be more efficient than `arr.copy()[:mid]`. Same basic principle though.

Comment: In general it isn't a good idea to replicate `list` code with numpy arrays.  Even when differences like these `views` don''t bite you, you'll loose performance.

Comment: Let loose the performance! 

Comment: @alaniwi Many thanks, that answered the problem! I had thought that you would get the same behaviour in both numpy and python arrays when using the same syntax... Oh well, live and learn.

Comment: @mimocha Best to refer to the builtin type as lists rather than arrays, by the way.

Comment: @alaniwi Gotcha, I'm definitely not a python programmer at heart. By the way, how do I close this question when there's no answer reply. Do I just reply to myself now? I'm still new to posting/commenting on this site.

Comment: @mimocha That's fine, you just leave it. People could still add an "answer", but if they do, it had better be justified by writing something more substantial than has already been written in the comments... ;-)

Comment: @alaniwi Alright, thanks again!